# Django let me log in in Firefox but not in chrome

Tags: python, django, google-chrome

I recently started playing with Django.

When I try to log in into the admin panel, it succeeds in Firefox but doesn't in Google Chrome.

This is the error i get : 
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /admin/login/

My cookies are enabled in Chrome for every website. Is there a specific reason why it would work in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and the solution for me was to set Django setting

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
```

I know this is the default setting but I've been using production config with this set to `True`. So in my dev settings I changed it to `False` and was able to log in to admin panel in Chrome.

On Feb 2020 Chrome implemented a change that enforces that *Secure* cookies are only accessible via HTTPS protocol. So if you're developing locally and only using HTTP that is a killer. Firefox and Edge are yet to enforce *Secure* flag |(based on taday's versions)

Answer (score 0):

Are you not developing using the c9 platform?

https://c9.io/

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. No, I'm not using the c9 platform. Should I?

Comment: Oh, it's okay. No, actually I asked why I had the same problem when I was developing with Django inside the c9 platform. So I asked if you were using her.

Answer (score 0):

I reset my chrome setting and it worked fine.
In Chrome, click on the 3 dots on the far right and goto settings.
On settings page, scroll all the way down or click on the bottom left "Reset Settings" button and reset settings.